# See how many times my free iPhone app has been downloaded

Tags: iphone, statistics

Is there a way I can see how many times my iPhone app has been downloaded?

I've found on this forum you can see it under Sales and Trends, but there is no daily report to be found.

Do the stats of a free app come there too? or is it only for apps you have to pay for?
If so, is there a way to find out how many times my free app has been downloaded?

Comment: You get the info under sales and trends for free apps too.

Comment: yeah there is a bar chart in 'Sales and Trends'. Do you not have it???

Comment: No, the app has been released for 2 days, could this be the problem? But since there is a 'Daily report' I would think that it should be there already.. It says `No reports are currently available. `

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You CAN see daily reports (even for free apps) under Sales and Trends, but those reports are created in the morning. SO, if your app just came out today, you won't see anything under Sales and Trends until tomorrow morning around 8 or 9AM. However, Apple can (and has been known to) take longer than that to release the previous day's report.

Comment: Ok, The app has been released 2 days ago, I guess that they will be slower with releasing it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem (: 
Don't hesitate to come back to this question if you don't see anything soon. My first app took a few days to appear as well.

Answer (score 5):

There is a iPhone app by Apple to view sales. It will also show free downloads.

http://www.macrumors.com/2010/06/10/apple-releases-itunes-connect-mobile-app-for-developers/

Comment: Isn't that the mobile version of the iTunesConnect website? Because the stats aren't available on the website, so I think they won't be available there either.

Comment: It's a native app that talks iTunesConnect (I guess) and it can show more numbers than the website I think. I can definitely see "Free Apps (iOS)" in iTC Mobile. It can take some time for them to aggregate all downloads as there are many AppStores (for each country).

Answer (score 2):

On the Sales screen in iTunes Connect, there is a date/year just under the menu bar on the right. Clicking that date will bring up the options for the date range of the report. This enables you to see your downloads or sales for the day/week/month/year selected.

Be sure to specify your desire to see free, paid, or all by clicking the current selection (free, paid, all) located just under the iOS heading at the top of the page.

I dressed up a screenshot to illustrate, but I don't have enough reputation points to post it!
It's posted to G+ instead: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-OMg1J922zm0/UtWYErBSlwI/AAAAAAAAGe8/E87ySSOjWnM/w426-h273/iTunes+Connect+Screenshot.png

Answer (score 1):

Apple just updated https://itunesconnect.apple.com site you can adjust the date range in the middle of screen (using the slider) or by adjusting the dates on top left corner after navigating to sale and trends screen to see how many downloads you have had.
 [image]